# Оформление строк python 3

Tags: python-3.x, строки, оформление

Хочу реализовать красивый таймер и столкнулся с проблемой. Цифры я хочу сделать символами, что б они выглядели лучше, да и побольше были. Но при сложении двух строк они идут следом (одна вверху, другая внизу). Я же хочу сделать по порядку слева направо. Вот так, естественно, оно не работает:

```
n1 = str("""
████
██─█
█──█
██─█
██─█
██─█
████
""")

n0 = str("""
██████
█────█
█─██─█
█─██─█
█─██─█
█────█
██████
""")

print(n1 + n0)
```

У меня нет идей как это реализовать, буду очень благодарен любой помощи!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import operator

font = [
    ['██████', '██████',],
    ['██  ██', '███ ██',],
    ['█ ██ █', '██  ██',],
    ['█ ██ █', '███ ██',],
    ['█ ██ █', '███ ██',],
    ['██  ██', '███ ██',],
    ['██████', '██████',],
]

def fmt(digits):
    getter = operator.itemgetter(*digits)
    return '\n'.join(' '.join(getter(row)) for row in font)

print(fmt([0, 1, 1, 0, 0]))
```

```
██████ ██████ ██████ ██████ ██████
██  ██ ███ ██ ███ ██ ██  ██ ██  ██
█ ██ █ ██  ██ ██  ██ █ ██ █ █ ██ █
█ ██ █ ███ ██ ███ ██ █ ██ █ █ ██ █
█ ██ █ ███ ██ ███ ██ █ ██ █ █ ██ █
██  ██ ███ ██ ███ ██ ██  ██ ██  ██
██████ ██████ ██████ ██████ ██████
```

Answer (score 4):

```
n1 = str("""
████
██─█
█──█
██─█
██─█
██─█
████
""")

n0 = str("""
██████
█────█
█─██─█
█─██─█
█─██─█
█────█
██████
""")

n1 = n1.split()
n0 = n0.split()

for i in range(len(n1)):
    print(n1[i] + n0[i])
```